# How is Alice so skilled in "Resident Evil: Retribution" if she was stripped of her superhuman powers?

Tags: resident-evil

At the end of Resident Evil Retribution, Wesker injects Alice with the T-Virus, returning her former powers, which supposedly he took away in a former movie. But in this movie, we see Alice being an excellent shooter, killing everybody and monsters, being an excellent driver, being an excellent martial artist etc. Watching Alice in other movies such as Extinction, or the Final Chapter, I don't remember seeing differences between her when she had superhuman powers and when she supposedly had not. How is this possible, which are the differences between superhuman Alice and the Alice who was taken away her powers?

Comment: "which supposedly he took away in a former movie" -> he takes her powers away in the previous movie, "Resident Evil: Afterlife"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal Alice was a highly trained operative we never see her disobeying the laws of physics we simply see her doing things that would hurt like hell in the morning or even 5 seconds after doing it, however as a highly trained operative Alice would have the ability to push through pain and fatigue until she was unable to function or she completed her objective.

Super Alice most likely felt less pain and fatigue than normal Alice, the regenerative effects of the T-virus acting as a kind of steroid allowing her to push her body harder and to recover faster from the intense physical activity as well as giving her a slight healing factor that allowed her to survive at the end of Apocalypse.

Super Alice also had psionic abilities however it wasnt clear how voluntary these were.